# Italic section title with non-italic numbers in memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I would like to have the printed title of my sections be in italic, with the numbering in Roman format (not Roman numerals, though).  Yet, using the `memoir` commands for section formatting, the `\itshape` in the `setsecheadstyle` appears to be overriding the rest of the format.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setsecnumformat{\rmfamily\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\rmfamily § \arabic{section}}
\setsecheadstyle{\itshape}
\begin{document}
    \section{A Test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to enclose the section number in a group with the declaration `\upshape`, the opposite of `\itshape`. Does `\renewcommand{\thesection}{{\upshape § \arabic{section}}}` work for you? (Not sure if you need the additional \rmfamily in this definition.)

Comment: @marquinho brilliant! If you make it into an answer I'm happy to accept

Comment: Great! Will do.

Comment: You don't want to `\renewcommand{\thesection}` that way. That's really a problem when you do cross-references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to add formatting commands in the definition of `\thesection`, because you'll get in troubles when cross-referencing.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setsecnumformat{\textnormal{§ \csname the#1\endcsname\quad}}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setsecheadstyle{\itshape}

\makeevenhead{headings}{\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
\createmark{section}{both}{shownumber}{\upshape § }{\quad\itshape}

\begin{document}

\section{A Test}

\end{document}
```

This is possibly a simplification and you may want to differentiate headers in left and right pages, but shows the main parts where to act.

[image]

Comment: (This is better, and more sensible, than my answer below!)

Answer (score 1):

To typeset text in the upright shape, the opposite of italicization, you can put it it in a group (delimited by braces) with the explicit *declaration* `\upshape`. The corresponding *commands* are `\textit` and `\textup`.
[Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Font_styles)'s a short reference of text styles and their relations.

Your MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setsecnumformat{\rmfamily\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{\rmfamily\upshape § \arabic{section}}}
\setsecheadstyle{\itshape}
\begin{document}
    \section{A Test}
\end{document}
```